Should the partition key be included in ORDER BY or PRIMARY lists?
I'm creating a new table in Clickhouse database like:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sensor_reading`
(
  test_day          Date,
  sensor            String,
  ts                DateTime,
  speed             Int32,
  weight            Int32, 
)
ENGINE=MergeTree()
PARTITION BY test_day
ORDER BY (test_day, sensor, ts)
PRIMARY KEY (test_day, sensor, ts);

The key sensor has a value space of much lower dimension than test_day, I want to use it as the 1st primary key, so clickhouse can index it by binary search. Since the table is partitioned by test_day, is it still necessary to put it in the ORDER BY or PRIMARY KEY lists? Should it be changed to ORDER BY (sensor, ts) or ORDER BY (sensor, test_day, ts)?
Edit: Most of my queries come with filters like WHERE test_day = '2024-10-01' AND sensor = 'A' AND ts BETWEEN ...

Try ORDER BY(sensor, ts). ClickHouse will use the partition to filter by day (if applicable). You definitely want sensor first

No, PARTITION BY could be entirely different fields which not related to ORDER BY or PRIMARY KEY clause in CREATE TABLE
PARTITION BY clause use during INSERT to split rows into different data parts, data parts in different partitions never merged
PARTITION BY clause use during SELECT to quick filter data parts which not related to query to avoid unnecessary disk reads
look https://kb.altinity.com/engines/mergetree-table-engine-family/pick-keys/
for details
